# Flutter: When I hot reload my Provider create new object

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my really first question, so if I made a mistake I'm very sorry.
I've found some similar questions about my problem, but none of them really fixed my situation.

So I'm using Provider 4.0.2 in my project, and when navigating by my app it's work fine, but when I try a hot reload my Provider lose the state and my object start from beginning again.

This is how I implement:

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<ExpenseDAO>(create: (context) => ExpenseDAO()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<ExpenseDAO, ExpensesData>(
            update: (context, dao, expensesData) => ExpensesData(dao: dao)),
        ChangeNotifierProvider<User>(create: (context) => User()),
      ],
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

**expense_data.dart**

```
class ExpensesData with ChangeNotifier {
  ExpensesData({@required this.dao}) {
    print('new object');
  }

  final List<Expense> _expenses = [];
  final ExpenseDAO dao;
  bool _isLoaded = false;

  bool get isLoaded => _isLoaded;

  UnmodifiableListView<Expense> get expenses => UnmodifiableListView(_expenses);

  saveExpense(Expense expense) async {
    await dao.insertExpense(expense);
    await loadList(expense.userId);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  loadList(String userId) async {
    _expenses.clear();
    _expenses.addAll(await dao.expenses(userId));
    _isLoaded = true;
  }
```

And that is the screen of my problem. When hot reload I got a new object, I can see this by printing "new object" when hot reload in the console, the list of expenses is empty after that and my property "isLoaded" come back to false.

**expenses_screen.dart**

```
class ExpensesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'expense_screen';

  @override
  _ExpensesScreenState createState() => _ExpensesScreenState();
}

class _ExpensesScreenState extends State<ExpensesScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: kColorBackground,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Text(
          'Expenses',
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Center(
              child: Consumer<ExpensesData>(
                builder: (context, expensesData, child) {

              return ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Text(
                        'Tag = ${expensesData.expenses[index].category} '
                        '// Value = ${expensesData.expenses[index].value}');
                  },
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                  itemCount: expensesData.expenses.length);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.add,
          size: 40,
        ),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, AddExpenseScreen.id);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can u guys help me?
I really think that's a problem im my code, but I can't figure what it is.

Comment: It's hard to understand what's your problem, specially with all that code, try to reproduce it with a smaller example and explain better what's happening that shouldn't happen.

Comment: @mFeinstein next time I'll try to make a better question, after your answer about the documentation I did solve the problem, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` [docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider-class.html), it says explicitly:

```dart
DON'T create the ChangeNotifier inside update directly.
This will cause your state to be lost when one of the values used updates
```

Which you are violating in:

```dart
update: (context, dao, expensesData) => ExpensesData(dao: dao)),
```

You should inject the new `dao` object into the previously created `ExpensesData` object, like (make `dao` not `final` anymore):

```dart
update: (context, dao, expensesData) => expensesData.dao = dao),
```

or

```dart
update: (context, dao, expensesData) => expensesData.update(dao)),
```

It depends on your particular code and taste.

Comment: omg, I've read the doc and didn't figure the mistake I've made, thank u so much! 
After reading your answers and the doc again I see that that I did not create the provider and made it directly in the update!! 

Tks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You also can pass the instance of first model in the create property, and return the same instance in the update property:

```
void main() {
  Provider.debugCheckInvalidValueType = null;
   runApp(
    MultiProvider(
     providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider<ExpenseDAO>(create: (context) => 
       ExpenseDAO()),
      ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<ExpenseDAO, ExpensesData>(
        create: (context) => ExpensesData(Provider.of<ExpensesDao>(context, 
        listen:false))
        update: (context, dao, expensesData) => expensesData,
      ChangeNotifierProvider<User>(create: (context) => User()),
     ],
    child: MyApp(),
   ),
  );
 }
```